# How to delete extra window in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've had some sort of hack into my Google Chrome source code. All my chrome tabs include this annoying window in the lower left (please see attached image).

[image: Google Chrome Window]

Can anyone tell me how to remove the code creating this window?

- I know the code was added through a malicious software that I've already uninstalled.
- The window changes font colors based on the source tab's content (CSS?).

Comment: If anyone can even tell me the proper vocabulary to describe the "extra window", that would be helpful. I'm not even sure how to ask this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings

--> Try to **Reset settings** for Chrome

--> **Clear browsing data..**

Also **download** AdwCleaner [from here](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/) and clean other garbage also.

Comment: Are you suggesting a specific action on your first bullet? What settings would I 'reset'? I've tried clearing the browsing data but this had no impact. I would like to resolve the issue without additional software if possible since this problem is a result of downloading some other software.

Comment: If I right-click on the window, I can go into "inspect element" and delete the code block to remove the window. This codeblock is originating from something in Chrome (not a local machine) so I'm asking how to prevent this codeblock from building this window each time a tab opens.

Comment: "Reset Settings" at the very bottom of Chrome's advanced settings worked.